# Next.js Recreate Adobe Extract PDF Visualizer

Tags: reactjs, pdf, next.js, extract

I use the Adobe PDF Extract API to extract data from a PDF. This works fine.
Now I would like to recreate the Visualizer Adobe uses on their website (on the left side)

Link: https://acrobatservices.adobe.com/dc-visualizer-app/index.html

I managed to show my pdf in next.js with react-pdf library. But how do I use the bounds attribute to display the outlines on top of the pdf, because these are not pixel. These are pdf coordinates.

Here the code to display the pdf:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-pdf-next-js-forked-tw5gdp?file=%2Fnext.config.js%3A2%2C4-4%2C5

Help appreciated

[image]

Comment: You might miss understood my question. I don't want to recreate the calculation of the bounds I just want to display the bounds the Adobe API gives me to have the same visualization on my website. This can't be too difficult, but I can't wrap my head around this.